How to check for gaps between date properties in a list of objects?
My mentor and I are current rewriting a functionality in our project. Among all the different stuff we have to do, there is a crucial part which involves checking if there are gaps between histories. Everything we do after depends on the checking of gaps. Here is the history class we have:
public class History : IEntityBase, IEntityDates
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    /* =================== Not Mapped properties =================== */

    [NotMapped]
    public bool HasGap { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsGapSixMonthsOrMore { get; set; }
}

Basically the method accepts a List and checks whether there is a gap.
Q: What is a gap?
A: A gap is defined as the minimum number of days between two dates (not including) in order for the HasGap property to be true.
Here is also some info about the types of histories we can expect and possible outcomes:

A history can have null EndDate (A), and this means that the history is still ongoing and every history whose StartDate is after A.StartDate will not have a gap.
In a sorted List, histories may overlap. This means that a history might end while another history started 2 months before the end.
A history will have a gap if histories[i].StartDate is before histories[i-1].EndDate for at least 7 (gap) days.
histories[i].IsGapSixMonthsOrMore is true histories[i].StartDate is before histories[i-1].EndDate for at least 6 months.
StartDate can also be null but it never is because we do that check in a different function when getting all the data

If I think of anything else I will write.
We wrote two different methods to calculate, but both of them depend on the list of histories to be sorted. So we are wondering if there is a way to do this check without depending on the list to be sorted?
His solution performs the calculation in half the time mine does.
Here is his:
public static void CalculateGaps(this List<History> dateRanges, int? gapThreshold)
{
    if (dateRanges == null || dateRanges.Count < 2 || gapThreshold is null)
        return;

    // Sort the ranges by Start date
    var sortedRanges = dateRanges.OrderBy(r => r.StartDate)
        .ThenBy(r => r.EndDate)
        .ToList();

    // Initialize the first range with no gap (as it's the first in the list)
    sortedRanges[0].HasGap = false;
    sortedRanges[0].IsGapSixMonthsOrMore = false;

    // Keep track of the latest 'end' date encountered
    DateTime currentMaxEnd = sortedRanges[0].EndDate?.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue;

    for (int i = 1; i < sortedRanges.Count; i++)
    {
        // If there's a gap between the current maximum end and the next range's start
        if (currentMaxEnd < sortedRanges[i].StartDate?.Date.AddDays(-gapThreshold.Value))
        {
            sortedRanges[i].HasGap = true; // Gap found

            // Check if the gap is more than 6 months
            sortedRanges[i].IsGapSixMonthsOrMore = sortedRanges[i].StartDate?.Date.AddMonths(-6) >= currentMaxEnd;
        }
        else
        {
            sortedRanges[i].HasGap = false;
            sortedRanges[i].IsGapSixMonthsOrMore = false;
        }

        // Update the max end to be the later of the current max end or this range's end
        var nextEnd = sortedRanges[i].EndDate?.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue;
        currentMaxEnd = currentMaxEnd > nextEnd ? currentMaxEnd : nextEnd;
    }
}

Here is mine, I was on the same track as his but could get a few test cases with multiple overlapping histories to pass. So I implemented some sort of queue to help out with overlapping ones:
public static void CalculateGapsV2(this List<History> histories, int? gapThreshold)
{
    if (histories.Count == 0)
        return;

    histories = histories.OrderBy(h => h.StartDate).ToList();

    var queue = new Queue<DateTime?>();

    histories[0].HasGap = false; // First entry has no previous history to compare with
    histories[0].IsGapSixMonthsOrMore = false; // First entry has no previous history to compare with

    queue.Enqueue(histories[0].EndDate?.Date);

    for (int i = 1; i < histories.Count; i++)
    {
        var previousEndDate = histories[i - 1].EndDate?.Date;
        var currentStartDate = histories[i].StartDate?.Date;

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            if (queue.Peek() is null) //ongoing history
            {
                histories[i].HasGap = false;
                histories[i].IsGapSixMonthsOrMore = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (queue.Peek() > currentStartDate)
            {
                histories[i].HasGap = false;
                histories[i].IsGapSixMonthsOrMore = false;
                queue.Enqueue(histories[i].EndDate?.Date);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                queue.Dequeue();
            }
        }

        if (queue.Count == 0)
        {
            if (currentStartDate is null)
            {
                histories[i].HasGap = false;
                histories[i].IsGapSixMonthsOrMore = false;
            }
            else
            {
                var gapDays = (currentStartDate.Value - previousEndDate.Value).TotalDays;

                //A gap is defined as total days between two employments
                //So if a gapThreshold = 1 
                //Has gap would be false if hist[0].EndDate = 2024-10-1 and hist[1].StartDate = 2024-10-2
                //But has gap would be true if hist[0].EndDate = 2024-10-1 and hist[1].StartDate = 2024-10-3
                //Since we only have one full day between, and that is 2024-10-2
                histories[i].HasGap = gapDays > gapThreshold;

                // The six month gap is defined as six months or more
                // hist[0].EndDate = 2024-1-15  and hist[1].StartDate = 2024-7-15
                // This would make the bool true
                // If startDate was 2024-07-14 -> IsGapSixMonthsOrMore would be false
                histories[i].IsGapSixMonthsOrMore = currentStartDate.Value.AddMonths(-6) >= previousEndDate.Value;

                queue.Enqueue(histories[i].EndDate?.Date);
            }
        }
    }
}

Summary and Question
Both of the methods pass all our test cases.
Just to confirm the question. Is there a more performant way to do this without depending on the list of histories to be sorted? If not, is there any room for improvement in the CalculateGaps() method?

and what exactly is your question? When the above code does what it should, where's the problem?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain "is there a way to do this check without depending on the list to be sorted?" Is written in the question body

@MakePeaceGreatAgain we are wondering if there is a better approach which might not involve the list to be sorted. If not then is there a way to improve the existing code of CalculateGaps().
Sorry for being a little bit vague

@MakePeaceGreatAgain We will be using this method more in the future, and we feel like it should not depend on the histories being sorted.
Ideally, we would like to just call the method on the list of histories and not do any sorting.

To, me a History having the HasGap porperties does not make sense. The state of that property depends on the relation of the current instance to another instance. So, there should be something outside that carries that information. What if a History has a gap with the previous History and the next? Are all 3 HasGap Properties true?

Yep HasGap makes only slightly sense here if it is in reference to the next or previous History Instance and what next/previous is needs a definition. And that definition might imply a specific sort.

Is that "histories[i].StartDate is before histories[i-1].EndDate" some kind of indirect definition? If yes the sort must be fitting.

It would also imply, that there cannot be History A spanning History B and C, right? Can there even be "simple" spanning? I mean can History A start before History B and end after ?

What is your problem about sorting? Go one step back and ask yourself about your workflo. You need to find gaps. How would you do that - say on a list of numbers? Would you really take every number and compare it to all other numbers just to indicate if you have a gap? I am pretty sure you'd sort the list to save some checks for numbers way outside your area of interest. In other words: sorting your history-objects makes absolutely sense to me. It would feel strange not to do that.

@Fildor It is a little hard to explain, but look at histories as contracts. In our case one Employee can have many histories. In your example, if we have histories A, B, and C and if all endDates are before the StartDate. A would not have a gap because it is the first one, B would have a gap because of the difference between B and A, and C would have a gap because of the difference between C and B.

@Fildor Q: can History A start before History B and end after?
A: Yes it can. Also if there is a history C and A spans over B and C. Even though there might be a gap between C and B, since A spans over all of them there would be no gap

Sounds like you want to calculate the ... let's call it "gap distance" between two adjacent elements and set HasGap = gd > 7d and Has6MonthGap = gd > 6mo (pseudo code) ? Where the gap distance is Starti - Endi-1 ? Assuming a presorted dataset, yes. Otherwise it will pretty much blow up.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Well... Now that you ask me I do not see a problem. I think both of us got a little bit tunnel visioned to the whole idea of not needing a sorted list. But now that would only add more complexity. The way you are putting it makes a whole lot of sense. Thanks for the input man!

Do you keep the Histories in a List<T> and sort it, or is it from a DB? I was thinking about using a DataStructure that's sorting in nature to begin with... in the exmaple you are using List<T> but would it make sense to use something else?

@Fildor Yeah, you're right. We get Histories from our DB. employee.Query().Include(d => d.History).ToList()

Ah, ok ... in that case it might make sense to have the DB do the sorting. But I guess you already have thought about that. I was also thinking about having the db calculate the "gap distance" ... I am sure, I have done something similar before ... I think we were using a self-join (?) - it has been a while ...

@Fildor Yeah basically to do this: employee.Query().Include(d => d.History.OrderBy(h => h.StartDate)).ToList()

I can only nitpick your implementation, but I'm guessing most of those points are because this is just a demo. However I do have one major point, both your start and end date are nullable, what does a null start date mean? Is a range of [2024-09-01, null], [2024-10-01, null] considered overlapping? What about [null, 2024-10-01], [2024-09-01, null]? And so on.

Your mentors solution should be O(n log n), I'm fairly certain that you cannot do better than that, at least not without additional assumptions. You could probably reduce the constant factor. Sorting in the database, or using the in place List.Sort might be faster. I don't think .ThenBy(r => r.EndDate) is needed, or helpful. You could early-out if an end-data is null, etc.

When EndDate is null, you said "..every history whose StartDate is after A.StartDate will not have a gap". Since the list is already sorted by StartDate, shouldn't you just finish processing the first time you encounter a null EndDate, since everything after that will not be relevant?
